# how to show that there is a permutation that sends any two numbers to two consecutive numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups

Is there a way to show the following: for any two numbers in [n]={1,2,...,n}, there is a permutation that sends them into two consecutive numbers in [n].

i.e, 
Choose $i,j\in [n]$, for any k, with $1\leq k\leq n-1$, there is a permutation $\sigma_{_{k}}$ such that $i\ \sigma_{_{k}} = k$ and  $j\ \sigma_{_{k}}= k+1$. I think the permutation depends on the position of $i,j$. I mean if $i,j$ are consecutaive then the identity is our desire permutation. However, if $i,j$ are not consecutive then the permutation is the one that sends $i\mapsto j-1,$ and  $j\mapsto j$.

i.e,  $2,4\in [5]$ and the permutation is for example $(23)$ or $(123)$. the problem that I couldn't prove it.

Comment: Not following. If $j=n$ then use the transposition $(i,n-1)$.  Otherwise use the transposition $(i,j+1)$.  Of course there are many others, but this one works.  Or were there other properties you wanted?

Comment: This seems like an incredibly obvious fact.  Are you familiar with two-line notation for permutations?  Are you aware that every possible arrangement of the numbers can occur on the second line, and in particular can have an arrangement that sends the specific elements to adjacent results?  You can construct an explicit permutation by starting as $\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&\dots&i&\dots&j&\dots&n\\ \square&\square&\dots&k&\dots&k+1&\dots&\square\end{pmatrix}$ and then fill the second row however you like, for example with the terms in order skipping over $k$ and $k+1$...

Answer (score 1):

A permutation of the set $S = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is just a rearrangement of the elements of $S$. The statement that you are trying to prove is almost trivially true.

For instance, choose $i,j \in S$. Then for $k$ such that $1\leq k < n$ let $\sigma_k$ be the permutation that swaps $i$ and $k$, swaps $j$ and $k+1$, and leaves all other elements of $S$ fixed. This is one explicit example of a permutation with the property you desire, but there are many more. Can you see why?